# How to compare a returned variable to input value in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am learning JavaScript and today I am trying to make a little guessing game for learning colors in English. So there is a box that changes colors randomly picked from an array on click. When the box changes the color my son should write the presented "color" in input form and check. Here is my code, the color is chosen randomly, the box changes its color. When there is no input its written - no value, but I have a problem with the correct color, when I enter the correct color I would like it to be written Bravo etc. I don't know why it's not working, when I compare

```
document.getElementById("inputResult") === pickedColor;
```

So all my code is below:

```
  <style>
    #box {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 3px black solid;
    }

    .red {
      background: red;
    }

    .purple {
      background: purple;
    }

    .blue {
      background: blue;
    }

    .white {
      background: white;
    }

    .green {
      background: green;
    }

    .brown {
      background: brown;
    }

    .orange {
      background: orange;
    }

    .yellow {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>


  <div id="box"></div>
  <button onclick="colorPicker.pickColorBtn()">Pick a colour</button>    
  <div id="pickedColor"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <input id="inputResult" type="text" size="15" placeholder="write the color" />
 <button onclick="colorPicker.checkResultBtn()">Check</button>
```

and the js:

```
var colors = [
  "red",
  "purple",
  "blue",
  "white",
  "green",
  "brown",
  "orange",
  "yellow"
];

var background = document.getElementById("box");

var colorPicker = {
  pickColorBtn: function() {
    var pickedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    document.getElementById("pickedColor").innerHTML = pickedColor; //just to see what color has been picked
    background.className = pickedColor;
  },
  checkResultBtn: function() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputResult").value === "") {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no value!!!!";
    } else if (document.getElementById("inputResult") === pickedColor) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "BRAVO THAT'S IT!!!";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        "SOMETHING ELSE is WRONG!!!";
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/hubkubas/pen/eLvbPZ?editors=1010

So I would be very thankful for your help and explanation what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You're missing `.value` from the end of the 2nd if statement

Comment: First of all this comparision is wrong `document.getElementById("inputResult") === pickedColor;`. You're not comparing the input value to the variable but the input reference itself. It should be `document.getElementById("inputResult").value === pickedColor;`.

Comment: also make sure to use `trim()` function and convert the `document.getElementById("inputResult").value` to lowercase before checking the `pickedColor`, as a kid may type in unnecessary blank spaces or change cases. Anything else (like other alphanumerics or symbols) is not permissible.

Comment: Small hint: You can set the box color directly without classes: `document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "purple"`

Comment: I would do a `console.log(pickedColor)` inside the `checkResultBtn` function to see if it has a value... It's defined in the `pickColorBtn` function, and therefore no longer exists inside the `checkResultBtn` function...

Comment: here a fixed version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EemmJL?editors=0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the "pickedColor" variable inside "pickColorBtn" 
    function is local to that function and not accessible outside.
    So "pickedColor" variable is not accessible in "checkResultBtn" and hence the equality 
    "document.getElementById("inputResult") === pickedColor" does not hold true.
    "pickedColor" is "undefined" inside "checkResultBtn" function.

The solutions to the problem are:-

1. Either declare "pickedColor" variable to a global variable.
2. or do not use "var" keyword while defining the "pickedColor" variable inside 
   "pickColorBtn" function making it by default a global variable(while not in "use 
   strict" mode).
3. or use "this.pickedColor" everywhere inside "colorPicker" object.

   Here is the first solution:-

```
    var colors = [
      "red",
      "purple",
      "blue",
      "white",
      "green",
      "brown",
      "orange",
      "yellow"
    ];

    var background = document.getElementById("box");
    var pickedColor;
    var colorPicker = {
    pickColorBtn: function() {
        pickedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        document.getElementById("pickedColor").innerHTML = pickedColor; //just to see 
        what color has been picked
        background.className = pickedColor;
      },
      checkResultBtn: function() {
        if (document.getElementById("inputResult").value === "") {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no value!!!!";
        } else if ((document.getElementById("inputResult").value === pickedColor) || 
          (pickedColor === undefined && document.getElementById("inputResult").value === 
            "white")) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "BRAVO THAT'S IT!!!";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
            "SOMETHING ELSE is WRONG!!!";
        }
      }
    };
```

Also you should compare using:

```
document.getElementById("inputResult").value === pickedColor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  checkResultBtn: function() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputResult").value === "") {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no value!!!!";
    } else if (document.getElementById("inputResult").value === pickedColor.innerHTML) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "BRAVO THAT'S IT!!!";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        "SOMETHING ELSE is WRONG!!!";
    }
  }
```

You were comparing uncorrectly the second condition by forgetting to add `.value`

Also, pickedColor is a html element and you have to check on it's `innerHTML`

Above code works :)

Comment: Are you sure it works? `pickedColor` is in fact a string: `var pickedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];` and is scoped to the `pickColorBtn` function. It's most likely `undefined` in the other function...

Comment: Yes, pickedColor when console logged gives `<div id="pickedColor">yellow</div>`

Definitely not the cleanest solution I agree, but for this case yes that's how it is

Comment: Oh, because of browser's fun habit of creating variables from elements with ids. Forgot about that.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ what can we do

Comment: Well, we can suggest they use a property of their `colorPicker` object to hold the chosen color...